# Connected to VPN, I can ping and remote into servers but cannot connect to http, svn or mssql

Tags: vpn

I have a problem where I can vpn into a network.  I am able to ping a certain server (devserver).  I can also do a remote desktop into the server.

However, if I try to access the server in other ways, for example:

http://devserver

or

connect to the SVN server on the devserver

or

connect to the MSSQL server on the devserver

I am unable to connect to the server.  All requests timeout.

What could be the problem?

Update:

Thank you for the responses.  Yes, it seems to be a firewall blocking me.  It seems to be the server's firewall since I can turn the server firewall off and get it even though my firewall is on.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to configure it.  It's the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Is there a firewall filtering your VPN connection?

Comment: You are right.  It has something to do with the firewall.  I discounted it from being a firewall issue because the one who set it up for me said he can connect without any problem.

Comment: That's probably because he made sure the firewall would let traffic for his machine go through. And that is the correct way to do this (reduce access to the minimum that will do the job).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others already wrote: Your VPN gateway is probably a Firewall and has some special rules. Another possibility could be a firewall on the server itself. Check this too! When I had this problem the last time it was the firewall on the server. (I searched several minutes on the firewall appliance because I believed the problem would be there.)

Comment: I think the server firewall is blocking me.  If I completely turn it off I can get in even though my firewall is up.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to configure it so it is on but still lets me in.

Comment: Probably the old IT guy configured on the VPN endpoint that he always gets the same IP address. And on the sever firewall he configured that this IP address is allowed to use all services. See "To configure Windows Firewall Port Exceptions" point 4 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875811.aspx Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Some firewall consider the VPN as a stand-alone inteface, thus applying either NAT ploicies and/or Firewall rules on that interface. Look at your Firewall Rules on VPN > LAN and/or Nat Policies from VPN > LAN.

Answer (score 2):

MTU issues + a firewall that won't fragment packets and drops the ICMP MTU Exceeded, is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Firewall in your way?

Answer (score -2):

Sometime, intermittent VPN issues are related to some hops dropping large packets. Try reducing packet size by lowering the VPN client virtual interface MTU. It solved a similar problem for me.